# Is Theory of Computation by Sipser a bad math reference?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, computational-mathematics

So, Professor Sipser's bio is unreal, I mean no disrespect to the man, nor do I think I could be half the mathematician he is. My issue is--and maybe this is me just not looking at these questions correctly--that the following sample of questions from his *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* appear to be ill conceived; and they're from Chapter $0$, which makes me question whether the book is worth continuing to read. Examples:

---

> **Exercises 0.2:** Formally describe the following sets:
>
> 1. The set containing the string $aba$.
> 2. The set containing the empty string.
> 3. The set containing nothing at all.

---

What I'm bothered by for all three of these questions is that they begin with "The" when clearly there are infinitely many sets that contain each. I don't know how to interpret these questions and I've never seen elementary set theory questions that seem so, what I would call, imprecise. Maybe they're posed this way intentionally or maybe I'm being a bit dense. Just looking for some advice on whether the book is worth it because I feel a bit disheartened by these.

Here's another example from the same section:

> The set containing the numbers $1, 10,$ and $100$.

I mean there are infinitely many of these. I interpret the word "contains", in set terminology, to mean "is a superset of". But then again, I'm a math novice, so it wouldn't surprise me if I was looking at this from a bad angle.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: To me, "the" means that we consider the set containing *precisely* the elements mentioned.

Comment: However, that's inconsistent witht the word "containing". At least in my experience with set theory.

Comment: fyi: A Google Books search on "the set containing" yields almost 78000 matches. In any case, that would be an extremely  poor criterion to judge the quality of a mathematics textbook.

Comment: "comprising" might be more idiomatic than "containing" here.

Comment: I'm not saying that "the set containing..." is an imprecise way of describing a set. What I'm saying is that expecting a single set to be derived from whatever completes that description is not generic considering one could claim there infinitely many sets satisfying a criterion. Look at example 1. Is that the way you would write that question? And if so, what do you mean by it?   I'm not trolling here. I don't want to read a book where the language isn't carefully chosen. It leads to an unnecessary amount of confusion and stack exchange posts.

Comment: What is your proposed better wording for "The set containing ..."?

Comment: "The set containing exactly... ", "The set containing only..." , "The set of elements [list of elements]... ", etc.

Comment: My intro analysis book uses "the set of..." for such descriptions.

Comment: I am downvoting this question as an useless rant. Mathematics and common language are different things, but that does not mean we cannot use pragmatics in math. To avoid abuses of language/notation just makes divulgation/communication much more difficult without solid pros, in my humble opinion.

Comment: The question is asking if Sipser's book is a bad math reference. And listed as a soft question. I cited some opening details of the book explaining why I'm asking, hoping to avoid a needless investment in the book, or on the contrary, somebody popping up and vouching for the book. What about that is a rant? Maybe you're talking about the comments?

Comment: @Zduff: I mean that, from my perspective, to criticize a book as a *bad math reference* because it refers to *the set containing $1,2,3$* and not to *the set* **only** *containing $1,2,3$* is plainly excessive. Elaborate way to say *come on, it is clear, what else should it be?*. There is nothing bad in loving mathematical rigor, but being too harsh on idioms/figures of speech/hidden assumptions won't bring anything good to you or to this thread. I know a thing or two about this kind of issues.

Comment: There are other things that strike me as off in the book's intro. All I'm asking is if anyone is familiar with the book and to let me know it's worth the time. That's it. If the book is known to be good, I'll adjust myself. If it's not, I'll pick up something else.

Answer (score 4):

In this context - and *essentially everywhere* - a phrase like "the set containing ---" means "the set containing *exactly* ---." So the set containing $1,2,3$ is just $\{1,2,3\}$. The indicator is the word "**the**" - there are many sets containing $1,2,$ and $3$, but "the set containing $1,2$, and $3$" is understood to refer to the unique set containing *exactly* $1,2$, and $3$.

Comment: Can you link me to a well known rigorous, but elementary math text that uses that style because all my intro level books (skimming through a few now) appear to be more specific, or using phrasing such as "the set **of** ... " rather "the set **containing**... ". The word *containing* means *has in it*. I don't see why anyone would use it to mean equality.

Comment: @Zduff Again, the crucial word isn't "containing," it's "**the**." Think of it this way: if I asked you to bring me "**the** box containing a book on agriculture," and you had a box containing exactly a book on agriculture and a different box containing a book on agriculture and a stuffed moose head, which box would you bring me? It's true that natural language is often used, even in mathematical contexts, in imprecise ways, but honestly this is a really small example.

Comment: It's analogous to saying "there are two people in this room" - while it's true that this statement is literally correct if there are five people in the room, it's generally going to be clear that it means *exactly* two people.

Comment: After some scarring memories with the words "and" and "or" in the set theory context I just wanted to make sure. M I've been burned not taking math sentences 100% literally.